# Java: Given a number, get the highest sequential occurrences in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java Programming (or programming infact).

I have an array which contains either `4` or `6` **only**. Given a number, either `4` or `6`, find the highest sequential occurrence of the given number.

I need highest sequential occurrence count

Example: `arr[{4,4,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,6}]`

If the above array is given, and next input number is `4`, the output should be `5`. Because the number `4` has occurred sequentially 5 times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String arrayTK = br.readLine(); // Input is 4466444446
int[] inpArray = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inpArray[i] = arrayTK.charAt(i) - '0';
}
int maxSequenceTimes = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    // Logic
}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Not sure about the logic part. Using hashmaps helps I guess. Need some code help/guidence

Comment: I suggest you implement a **state machine** algorithm within the loop, with two states: In case the previous digit was 4, and in case the previous digit was 6. Within each of them, increment the correspondant counter and reset the other. But you have to try for yourself. Don't expect SO to do your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String arrayTK = br.readLine(); // Input is 4466444446
```

Because your first input is a string, you don't need to convert it to an int array and if you are using you can use:

```
String arrayTK = "4466444446";
int result = Arrays.asList(arrayTK.replaceAll("(\\d)((?!\\1|$))", "$1;$2").split(";"))
        .stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get().length();
System.out.println(result);
```

Explanation :

- `arrayTK.replaceAll("(\\d)((?!\\1|$))", "$1;$2")` put a separator between each two different numbers the result should be  [`44;66;44444;6`](https://regex101.com/r/KTokLk/1)
- `.split(";")` split with this separator (i used `;` in this case) the result is `["44", "66", "44444", "6"]`
- `stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get()` get the max input
- `.length()` to return the length of the result

[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/UW3wdy)

**Edit**

> How I modify the same, to get count to any specific number. I mean, max sequential occurrence of number 4

In this case you can just add a filter `.filter(t -> t.matches(number + "+"))` which mean get only the numbers which match `4+` where 4 can be any number :

```
...
int number = 6;
int result = Arrays.asList(arrayTK.replaceAll("(\\d)((?!\\1|$))", "$1;$2").split(";"))
        .stream()
        .filter(t -> t.matches(number + "+"))
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get().length();
```

Comment: How I modify the same, to get count to any specific number. I mean, max sequential occurrence of number `4`

Comment: Sorry sir. What I meant in comment is, get the max sequential occurrence, for a specific number in the array. Ex: if `number = 4`, output `2`. If number = `4`, output `5`

Comment: @SteveJobs did you mean `if number = 6 output is 2`?

Comment: and this is what i do check my [solution here](https://ideone.com/maAlCV)

Comment: Nice, But it's complex for beginners. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

We will separate and count all sequences and then search in each sequence to know which sequence contain the biggest length.

```
int[] arr = {4,4,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,6};

    boolean newSeq = false;
    int diffrentSeq = 0;
    int currentNumber;
    //Get sequence numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        currentNumber = arr[i];
        if (i >= 1 && currentNumber != arr[i - 1])
            newSeq = true;
        else if (i == 0)
            newSeq = true;

        //It's new sequence!!
        if (newSeq) {
            diffrentSeq++;
            newSeq = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(diffrentSeq);
    int[] maxSequencSize = new int[diffrentSeq];
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSequencSize.length; i++) {
        int currentNum = arr[lastIndex];
        for (int j = lastIndex; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == currentNum) {
                maxSequencSize[i]++;
                lastIndex = j + 1;
            } else break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max(maxSequencSize));
```

You need to get max value which act the max sequence length:

```
 private static int max(int[] array){

    int maxVal = 0;
    for (int anArray : array) {
        if (anArray > maxVal)
            maxVal = anArray;
    }

    return maxVal;
}
```

Comment: Please read the question correctly. I dont occurrence count. I need highest sequential count

Comment: Check my answer@SteveJobs

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner br =new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = br.next();
        int arr[]=new int[str.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            arr[i]=str.charAt(i)-'0';
            //System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        int j=0;
        int count=1,max=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {

            if(i==0){
            j=arr[i];

            }
            else
            {
                if(arr[i]==j)
                {
                    count++;
                //System.out.println("  "+count);   
                }
                else
                {

                    if(max<count){
                        max=count;
                    }
                    count=1;
                    j=arr[i];

                }
            }
        }
        if(max<count){
            max=count;
        }

        System.out.println(max);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the work. Every time you find the matching value you start counting and when the streak is over you compare the length with the maximum length you have found so far.

```
public int logic(int[] inpArray, int num) {
    int count = 0, max = 0 

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        if(inpArray[i] == num) {
            count++
        else{
            if(count > max)
                max = count;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count > max)
        max = count;

    return max;
}
```